# Runtime problems with the Birthday Paradox

Tags: performance-tuning

I wrote a function to compute the probability of [Birthday Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)-type problems:

```
birthday[n_, x_] := 1 - Factorial[n] Binomial[x, n] / x^n
```

It computes [100 000, 2^32] after a few seconds but gets stuck for a long time on a million:

```
birthday[1000000, 2^32] // N
```

Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

Comment: What about using machine-precision numbers instead: `birthday[1000000., 2.^32]`?

Comment: @Xavier Wow, that was a lot faster. Nice answer. I wonder why doing that has such a dramatic effect?

Comment: I believe I have seen a solution to this which used exact arithmetic but I can't remember anything more.  Possibly from a ProjectEuler.net problem?